Could not resolve "ZIP_Open": /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libzip.dylib
I am trying to run android studio on Mac M1, but getting the following error :
The daemon has terminated unexpectedly on startup attempt #1 with error code: 1. The daemon process output:
1. Error occurred during initialization of VM
2. Could not resolve "ZIP_Open": /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/libzip.dylib 

Full Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/2bxjNxb6
My gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
android.useAndroidX=true 
kotlin.code.style=official
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio as well as changing JAVA_HOME environment variable. I tried searching the error but nowhere I found the exact same error.

What version of MacOS and AndroidStudio do you use?

Did you find solutions for this? I am facing the same error on my mac

@S.K I tried installing many different versions but not worked. I still don't know how to solve this error but what worked for me was this: Uninstall the android studio completely using this guide, create a new user account in mac, install latest android studio freshly in the new user

This is likely related to zsh:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-364055/Could-not-resolve-ZIPOpen-Applications-Android-Studio.app-Contents-jbr-Contents-Home-lib-libzip.dylib
